# Emgu CV Hand Gesture Recognition C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

i'm working on emgu cv asl recognition and i want to have an idea for matching the hand signs list with the current image in the video and pickingthe most one witch matched the image
I want just the tips to Make this program work
i am working with c# language

Comment: So, do think it's something of a hard work ?

Comment: No i just want the idea or the simplest way to do this or tips that can help me . cause i'm blocked in the images match,